# Bootstrap what will happen if I put more than 12 columns in a row?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

what will happen if I put more than 12 columns in a row?

Is there any explanation on this in Bootstrap docs?

Comment: Seems like the kind of thing you could try out for yourself more quickly than asking a question on here.

Comment: @chuck i just googled the same thing. Seems legit to me.

Comment: It IS explained in the docs. It's called [column wrapping](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-wrapping).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's totally fine. It just means they will bump down to the next visual row, and space out responsively. Everything is floated left for that very purpose.

I do think the naming of `.row` creates some confusion, because a `.row` can span multiple "rows" of divs depending on your screensize and the # of divs you stack up.

Answer (score -1):

No you can use like that; http://jsbin.com/gusawere/1, bootstrap 2.X had problems with that usage but 3.x dont.