# Trying to sort out algorithm for JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-float

In an attempt to improve this answer here: [How to make divs stack without spaces and retain order on smaller sizes - in Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32475502/how-to-make-divs-stack-without-spaces-and-retain-order-on-smaller-sizes-in-boo/32553919#32553919)

I have been trying to work out how to create a jQuery that will dynamically set the `margin-top` of divs depending on the accumulated height total in comparison to the height total of the adjacent column of divs.

The css:

```
div {outline:solid 1px red; }
// Set media container widths small to test code.
@media (min-width: 400px) {
.container {
    max-width: 1170px;
}
   .left {
    max-width:50%;
    width: 50%;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
} 
   .right {
    max-width:50%;
    width: 50%;
    float:left;
}  
}

@media (min-width: 150px) {
.container {
    max-width: 400px;
}
.col-sm-12 {
    width: 100%;
}
}
```

The Html:

```
<div id="1" class="left col-sm-12" style="height:100px;background-color:yellow;">DIV 1</div>
<div id="2" class="right col-sm-12" style="height:80px;">DIV 2</div>
<div id="3"  class="left col-sm-12" style="height:50px;background-color:yellow;">DIV 3</div>
<div id="4" class="right col-sm-12" style="height:70px;">DIV 4</div>
<div id="5" class="left col-sm-12" style="height:20px;background-color:yellow;">DIV 5</div>
<div id="6" class="right col-sm-12" style="height:80px;">DIV 6</div>
<div id="7" class="left col-sm-12" style="height:50px;background-color:yellow;">DIV 7</div>
<div id="8" class="right col-sm-12" style="height:90px;">DIV 8</div>
```

Js:

```
$(function () {
// Get div by id.
var idR = $("div").attr('id');
var idNumder =parseInt(idR);
// check if it's a right div.
if((idNumber % 2 ==0) && (idNumber > 2)){

var className = $("div").attr('class');
var leftHeight = 0;
var rightHeight = 0;

for(int i =0; i<idNumber; i++){
// count up left side heights.
if(className.localeCompare("left")==0){
   leftHeight += $("#"+idNumber.ToString()).height;
}
 // count up right side heights.
 if(className.localeCompare("right")==0){
    rightHeight += $("#"+idNumber.ToString()).height;
}

   var diff = leftHeight - rightHeight;
   // Determine which side is shorter.
   if(leftHeight > rightHeight){
        $("#idR").css({
        "margin-top":"-"+ diff + "px",
    });
   }
    else{
        var idL = (idNumber + 1).toString();
       $("#idL").css({
        "margin-top":"-"+ diff + "px",
        "clear":"both",
    });
    }
}
}
});
```

The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kermit77/hswxc06w/26/

[image]

The idea is, that the difference in height is applied as a negative top margin to the shorter div, bringing it up flush under the dive above it.

[image]

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong, I suspect it is more than one thing. I've been fiddling around with it (no pun intended) and cannot make it work.

I don't think it's being acted on at all.

I'd appreciate any feedback

---

I solved this with the accepted answer's help, see full code here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32553919/3956566

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at my way of figuring out a solution for this.

I took a couple of new divs and made the existing divs to hide behind, then appended the divs as per class to right and left of the two divs.

[JS fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/eack0qm5/)

The below is my code for adding the existing divs into two new divs

```
$('#div1').css("float", "left");
$('#div2').css("float", "right");

$('#div1').append($('.left'));
$('#div2').append($('.right'));
```

Comment: Im glad the solution was helpful to you. Happy coding. :)