# Bootstrap4 Alpha: Using <div class="row">

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, row, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I do have a question related to using  in [Bootstrap 4 Alpha](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/).

Let's assume we need following html div structure

```
Box 50% width, Box 50% width

Box 50% width, Box 50% width

Box 50% width, Box 50% width
```

The, is it more appropriate to say

**Variant 1**:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-6"></div>
<div class="col-lg-6"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-6"></div>
<div class="col-lg-6"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-6"></div>
<div class="col-lg-6"></div>
</div>
```

Or **Variant 2**:

```
<div class="row">

<div class="col-lg-6"></div>
<div class="col-lg-6"></div>

<div class="col-lg-6"></div>
<div class="col-lg-6"></div>

<div class="col-lg-6"></div>
<div class="col-lg-6"></div>

</div>
```

As all of the examples on the Bootstrap page have row included by default, I couldn't tell whether this is also true for multiple elements.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variant 2 [will work](http://www.bootply.com/ff1VCRQwMG). This has [already been answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732763/bootstrap-3-nested-row-can-i-have-columns-add-up-to-more-then-12) for Bootstrap 3, and Bootstrap 4 works the same. It's ok to have more than 12 `col-*-*` units in a single `row` tag. It's called ["column wrapping"](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-wrapping).

From the Bootstrap docs..

> "If more than 12 columns are placed within a single row, each group of
>   extra columns will, as one unit, wrap onto a new line."

You just need to be aware that if your column content varies in height, you should use [responsive resets](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets) to "clear" the columns so that they wrap evenly.

**Example with clearfix resets:**
http://www.bootply.com/C4BMA2nDth