# Boostrap row on multiple lines

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like the fields of my form to be placed differently on desktop and on tablet. For now, everything is fine on desktop. I have two similar cases. In the first one, I have something like this (the input fields are in the div's) :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6"></div>
</div>
```

It doesn't look bad on tablets, but instead of having only one field in the 3rd and 6th rows, I would like to have two. Should I use just one "row" instead of 2, and use empty "col-md-3" 's on desktop in order to have a single "row" going across multiple lines?

In the end I have a similar case :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6"></div>
</div>
```

I would like the two first fields to be on the same line.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, put them all in a single `.row` element.** This is known as column wrapping.

Demo: http://www.codeply.com/go/7mUSsbO8od

**From the Bootstrap docs:**

> "If more than 12 columns are placed within a single row, each group of extra columns will, as one unit, wrap onto a new line"

There are also examples in the docs that demonstrate [column wrapping](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-wrapping). Just remember you may need to use responsive resets, if the columns vary in height.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6"></div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I haven't tried it but I don't think it's gonna work. Just having a col-md-6 at the top would change the desktop design. I'm not following.